# Why is linq to object implementing iterators manually?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects, .net-core

While browsing the .net core source i notice that even in source form iterator classes are manually implemented instead of relying on the yield statement and auto IEnumerable implementation.

You can see at this line for example the decalartion and implementation of the where iterator https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L168

I'm assuming if they went through the trouble of doing this instead of a simple yield statement there has to be some benefit but i can't immediately see which, it seems pretty similar to what i remember the compiler does automatically from i read back eric lippert's blog a few years back and i remember when i naively reimplemented LINQ with yield statements in it's early days to better understand it the performance profile was similar to that of .NET version.

It piqued my curiosity but it's also an actually important question as i'm in the middle of a fairly big data - in memory project and if i'm missing something obvious that makes this approach better i would love to know the tradeoffs.

Edit : to clarify, i do understand why they can't just yield in the where method (different enumeration for different container types), what i don't understand is why they implement the iterator itself (that is, instead of forking to diferent iterators, forking to diferent methods, iterating diferently based on type, and yielding to have the auto implemented state machine instead of manual case 1 goto 2 case 2 etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason is that the specialized iterators perform a few optimizations, like combining selectors and predicates and taking advantage of indexed collections.

The usefulness of these is that some sources can be iterated in a more optimal way than what the compiler magic for `yield` would generate. And by creating these custom iterators, they can pass this extra information about the source to subsequent LINQ operations in a single chain (instead of making that information available only to the first operation in the chain). Thus, all `Where` and `Select` operations (that don't have anything else between them) can be executed as one.

Comment: If you check the edit to my question you'll see that indexed collection explains custom forking but not necessarily implementing the iterator yourself, i'm just surprised the introduced so much compiler magic to support linq and aren't using it in the implementation

Comment: However  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L122 seems to make you right about combining selectors with where. Althought i don't see why the iterator had to be implemented instead of simply passed to a whereselect that takes 2 fund and would also yield, i'm really not seeing why they manually do the iterator work

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Let me clarify. If you perform a LINQ operation on an array, you can take advantage of its indexer. But if you perform another operation on that result (and assuming the result was now a "generic" iterator), then the next operation will have lost the ability to leverage the indexer (because, as far as the second operation is concerned, the source is now a "generic" enumerable). By creating custom iterators, they are allowing multiple LINQ operations to take advantage of the indexer (instead of allowing it for just the first operation in the chain). Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Actually yes that makes sense, if you simply yielded instead of returning the iterator then chaining to another method would chain to the IEnumerable<T> version (like it does now) but there would be no way for them to check for is "whateveriterator" because it would be an auto generated type, that actually makes perfect sense on why they're doing it manually. Will make this as an answer

Comment: Yep. Incidentally, `yield`'s compiler magic wasn't introduced to support linq, it's been in .NET since 2.0 which is some time before linq.